# How to show only the last value of a for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm working on building a loop right now that only shows the end value. However, the code is showing all the integers though.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int sum = 0;

void findMultiples(int n){

    cout <<"Enter a positive integer:"<<endl;
    
  for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    if (i % 3 == 0)
      cout << "Sum: "<<(sum =sum+i)<<endl;
  
}

int main() {

  int num;
  cin>>num;

  findMultiples(num);


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Umm... if you don't want output in multiple iterations, then don't tell the computer to output in every third iteration? The computer is only doing what you told it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `for` then `if` then showing output. The `for` and `if` scope area is one line without `{ }`, so you are printing and summing at the same time and it is each time in the scope of `if` statement.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int sum = 0;

void findMultiples(int n){

    cout <<"Enter a positive integer:"<<endl;
    
  for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    if (i % 3 == 0)
      sum =sum+i;
  cout << "Sum: "<<sum<<endl;

  
}

int main() {

  int num;
  cin>>num;

  findMultiples(num);


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `cout` statements are in the wrong places. Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int findMultiples(int n){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {

    cout << "Enter a positive integer:" << endl;

    int num;
    cin >> num;

    cout << "Sum: " << findMultiples(num) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```